# ¿Es correcto que un usuario rechace una edición?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas

Espero se encuentren bien, soy usuario de SOes desde hace casi un mes y estoy aprendiendo a usar el sitio correctamente, me gusta entrar a algunas preguntas y leer las consultas y poder aprender un poco de ellas, en este caso mire un pequeño error por parte del usuario en su pregunta entonces solicite una edición, me la rechazaron y esa persona quien la rechazó hizo la misma edición quedándose con el crédito, por así decirlo.

A lo que quiero llegar es que el moderador realizo la misma edición que yo había hecho y se le dio por buena.

Seguramente no estoy en posición de reclamar, pero me gustaría saber la razón por la que se me rechazo la edición, si se requiere por parte de otro moderador pongo pruebas.

Saludos.

EDICIÓN

He editado el título de la pregunta ya que se me ha aclarado quien rechazo la edición fue un usuario con una reputación alta y no un moderador como tal.

Comment: Conviene que edites tu pregunta para entender el contexto. Este tipo de preguntas se responden con _depende_ si es que no se conoce el caso en particular.

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias por tu comentario, edite la pregunta, pero no creo que pueda ser más específico, más que una pregunta también puede ser una reclamación.

Comment: Que pregunta fue?

Comment: @Japv https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/613396/como-encontrar-palabras-entre-varios-caracteres-y-convertir-a-n%c3%bameros

Comment: 1. Quien mencionás no es un moderador (bueno, técnicamente _todos_ lo somos, lo que no es es un moderador _diamantado_); 2. Pulsá en _Markdown en paralelo_ para ver las diferencias. Lo que tiene de diferente es que le agregó el formato del lenguaje correspondiente. Y el mensaje de rechazo dice: _Esta edición no ha corregido problemas graves en la publicación - mira el historial de revisiones para ver qué debería haberse cambiado._

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias por aclararlo, e igual estuve revisando su edición con la mía sigo sin ver alguna diferencia. Igualmente te agradezco el que me lo hayas aclarado.

Comment: Por lo menos a mi me pasa que es más fácil rechazar y editar......quizás eso fue lo que pasó

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No se porque afirmas que fue un moderador el que rechazo tu edición. Una edición puede ser rechazada tanto por un moderador diamantado, como por el propio usuario que hizo la pregunta o por usuarios que tengan la reputación suficiente para vetar ediciones, en este último caso creo que se necesitan tres usuarios que voten para rechazar una edición. Como tú eres nuevo en el sitio y tienes poca reputación cualquier edición que hagas será llevada a la cola de revisión de ediciones donde usuarios con la suficiente reputación revisarán tu edición y la validarán o no, si tres usuarios con la reputación suficiente no están de acuerdo con tu edición esta no será validada, por tanto será rechazada.

Comment: Como lo mencione, soy nuevo, no sabía que cualquier usuario podía rechazar una edición y supuse que era un moderador por tener el 'poder', por así decirlo, de rechazar mi publicación, gracias por aclararlo.

Comment: @DevArthur vale, te recalcó, no es cualquier usuario, son aquellos usuarios cuya reputación le da privilegios para aceptar o no una edición, a medida que vayas participando en el sitio irás aumentando tu reputación y adquiriendo nuevos privilegios de moderación.

Comment: Claro, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarte.

Comment: @DevArthur no es cualquier usuario tampoco jajajaja, en teoria para tener acceso a las colas de revision necesitas cierta reputacion y ademas, no intervenimos en lenguajes que no conoscamos asique muchas cosas que se editan y no entendemos , no las rechazamos ni aprobamos, le damos omitir y que alguien que sepa del lenguaje se encargue.

Answer (score 6):

Moderadores, somos todos..

Hay moderadores electos (como yo) que tenemos un poco mas de poder que el resto, pero el sitio se automodera por todos, cuando tienen los suficientes privilegios.

En este caso, para mi punto de vista, tenes razón. La mejora en la edición posterior no mejora nada, porque era totalmente innecesario agregar el lenguaje. Sin embargo, no tomes en cuenta lo que hizo el usuario como un ataque, ya que simplemente, despues de los 2000 puntos de reputacion, toda edicion que hagas ya no suma nada. Asi que muy probablemente, lo hizo con la mejor intencion, sin notar el detalle de que cancelaba la tuya.

Comment: Cierto, he leído en varias partes que hay que mantener el sitio limpio y comprendo que fue para bien, muy probable con el tiempo aprenda a utilizar mejor la página, gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder.

Comment: añadiendo a lo que dice Gbianchi, por cada vez que subas de nivel el sitio te da mas privilegios para moderar aqui esta la lista de [privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) que se van otorgando de acuerdo a tus puntos

Answer (score 5):

Yo fui quien rechazó tu edición. No lo hice con mala intención, tal vez me equivoqué al seleccionar la opción que se presenta al revisar las ediciones. Pido disculpas por haber realizado la revisión de forma descuidada.

Hace mucho tiempo que pasé por tu posición, y recuerdo haber recibido rechazos de edición en más de una oportunidad. Lo que no recordaba era el mensaje un tanto rudo al momento de ser rechazada una edición.

Mi intención fue mejorar tu edición añadiendo simplemente el lenguaje al marcador de código en la pregunta. Pero, por alguna razón, escogí la opción de "rechazar y mejorar" en vez de sólo "mejorar".

Intentaré que no vuelva a suceder, ya que comprendo que puede causar alguna molestia o incomodidad, sobre todo cuando la edición no tiene nada malo, como en tu caso.

Comment: Gracias por aclararlo, igual ya se me explico todo el proceso y entiendo que pudo deberse a un mal entendido.
Saludos.

Comment: quizas podriamos cambiar el titulo del boton "rechazar y mejorar" pero eso es otro meta, pasa muy amenudo que al final uno lo que quiere es agregar una correccion y termina descartando cambios que un usuairo acomodo previamente

Comment: descuidado! jsjs